# Recovery service Vault error while adding Policies for SQL Backup

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am creating backup policies via Azure ARM Template to backup weekly for SQL Backup and i got following error. Any help would be appreciated.

I believe backupmanagementype for vm is AzureIaasVM so for SQL it would be **"backupManagementType": "AzureWorkload"**

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('policyName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/', parameters('vaultName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        **"backupManagementType": "AzureWorkload"**,
        "schedulePolicy": {
          "scheduleRunFrequency": "Weekly",
          "scheduleRunDays": "[parameters('scheduleRunDays')]",
          "scheduleRunTimes": "[parameters('scheduleRunTimes')]",
          "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy"
        },
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "dailySchedule": null,
          "weeklySchedule": {
            "daysOfTheWeek": "[parameters('scheduleRunDays')]",
            "retentionTimes": "[parameters('scheduleRunTimes')]",
            "retentionDuration": {
              "count": "[parameters('weeklyRetentionDurationCount')]",
              "durationType": "Weeks"
            }
          },
          "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy"
        },
        "timeZone": "[parameters('timeZone')]"
      }
    }
```

I got the following error

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 01:43:52 PM - Resource Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies 'RSVault2/SQL Backup' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "BMSUserErrorInvalidPolicyInput",
    "message": "Input for create or update policy is not in proper format\r\nPlease check format of parameters like schedule time, schedule days, retention time and retention days ",
    "target": null,
    "details": null,
    "innerError": null
  }
}'
At C:\Users\user\VSCode Azure\ARM Templates\301-Create Policies for Recovery Service Vault\rsv-policies-deploy.ps1:22 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 01:43:57 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At C:\Users\VSCode Azure\ARM Templates\301-Create Policies for Recovery Service Vault\rsv-policies-deploy.ps1:22 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 01:43:57 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At C:\Users\VSCode Azure\ARM Templates\301-Create Policies for Recovery Service Vault\rsv-policies-deploy.ps1:22 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

Comment: If you want to backup SQL on Azure VM, you can try to change the backupManagementType to AzureIaasVM. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you are providing scheduled run times and retention times in datetime format and not in time format?

It should be of format- "2018-01-24T10:00:00Z" for both scheduled run times and retention times.